# Beautiful soup. How to find all links with 3 attributes

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I find all links which have 3 attributes using beautiful soup?

I would like to find all links which include all attributes:

```
a id="js_24" class="_27jf _3emk" data-hover="tooltip"
```

I tried such way:

```
emo = soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'fjs_24', 'class': '_27jf _3emk', 'data-hover':"tooltip"})
```

but no sucess. I get no results.

Full link looks so:

```
<a id="js_24" class="_27jf _3emk" data-hover="tooltip" aria-label="6 Wow" href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=909182312524600&av=100011414120311" rel="ignore" role="button" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: Is the id not unique?

Comment: Nope, it is not so easy ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your logic, the problem is the *id* is wrong, you have `fjs_24` when the actual id is `js_24`:

```
emo = soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'js_24', 'class': '_27jf _3emk', 'data-hover':"tooltip"})
```

You can see it works once you make the change:

```
In [10]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


In [11]: soup = BeautifulSoup("""<a id="js_24" class="_27jf _3emk" data-hover="tooltip" aria-label="6 Wow" href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=909182312524600&av=100011414120311" rel="ignore" role="button" tabindex="-1"></a>""","lxml")


In [12]: soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'fjs_24', 'class': '_27jf _3emk', 'data-hover':"tooltip"})
Out[12]: []

In [13]: soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'js_24', 'class': '_27jf _3emk', 'data-hover':"tooltip"})
Out[13]: [<a aria-label="6 Wow" class="_27jf _3emk" data-hover="tooltip" href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=909182312524600&amp;av=100011414120311" id="js_24" rel="ignore" role="button" tabindex="-1"></a>]
```

If you have *lxml* installed, you can do it a lot faster and more concise using a *css selector*:

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(""""<a id="js_24" class="_27jf _3emk" data-hover="tooltip" aria-label="6 Wow" href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=909182312524600&av=100011414120311" rel="ignore" role="button" tabindex="-1"></a>""")

print(tree.cssselect("#js_24[class='_27jf _3emk'][data-hover='tooltip']"))
```

Comment: Thanks :) But how to print it out? for em in emo:
    print em.text doesn't work

Comment: @AnnaK, if you are only looking for one use find in place of find_all, find_all looks for multiple matches and returns a list/ResultSet

Comment: If you want the text of multiple then just `[a.text for a in emo]`